# Working with data fetched by Apollo React

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I'm trying to create a component that fetches data using Apollo. And the component has the search/filter feature. And the filter could be done with the local(current) data or in the server. I'm not sure how to handle both features with Apollo. With Redux I could dispatch two separate actions where both would in the end update the data in the Redux store. But I'm not sure how to access the data in Apollo to do filter locally(in client).

Here is simplified version of my component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import AnotherComponent from './AnotherComponent';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        searchTerm: '',
        data: [],
    }

    filterData = () => {
        // some sort of filtering. No issue with this.
    }

    handleSearchTermChangeLocal = searchTerm => {
        const data = this.filterData([howToGetDataFromApollo], searchTerm);
        this.setState({ data, searchTerm });
    }

    render() {
        const { query, variables } = this.props;

        return (
            <Query query={query} variables={variables}>
                {({ loading, data, error }) => (
                    <AnotherComponent
                        {...this.props}
                        isLoading={loading}
                        data={data}
                        error={error}
                        onSearchTermChange={handleSearchTermChange}
                    />
                )}
            </Query>
        );
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Can you do something like `handleSearchTermChangeLocal => data => searchTerm => {...}` so you pass it data in your render method? `onSearchTermChange={handleSearchTermChange(data)}`

Comment: So its alright to query in every render even if we are doing client side filter?

Comment: Apollo's `<Query />` render prop by definition lives in your render method. I think it's smart enough not to refetch data on every render if that's what you're worried about. In general React is moving in the direction of having code logic in render, like the React Hooks API.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand this:

> And the filter could be done with the local(current) data or in the server.

In your example you are only making the filter on the client side.

In my opinion, the best option for your is to split the code in two components.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import Filter from './Filter';

function MyComponent() {
    render() {
        const { query, variables } = this.props;

        return (
            <Query query={query} variables={variables}>
                {({ loading, data, error }) => (
                    <Filter
                        {...this.props}
                        isLoading={loading}
                        data={data}
                        error={error}
                    />
                )}
            </Query>
        );
    }
}
```

Filter Component:

```
import AnotherComponent from './AnotherComponent';

filterData = () => {
    // some sort of filtering. No issue with this.
}

class Filter extends Component {
    state = {
        searchTerm: '',
        data
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        return { data: filterData(props.data, state.searchTerm };
    }

    handleSearchTermChangeLocal = searchTerm => {
        const data = filterData(this.state.data, searchTerm);
        this.setState({ data, searchTerm });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AnotherComponent
                 {...this.props}
                 data={this.state.data}
                 onSearchTermChange={handleSearchTermChange}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

I wrote the code here in stack overflow directly, that are problem spelling problems and you can improve the logic, my idea here was just to write the code to answer your question